# Convert confuse code into Recursive function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, recursive-datastructures

i have a function that build a Select component, using an array with objects called "Service categories" inside this, we can (or not) have an array of child items that will come with a new "service category" (a subcategory with the same structure).
Actually i have this code (ugly, but working code)

```js
function buildMenu() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const newOptions = [];
    categories.map((category) => {
      const newCategory = {
        ...category,
        csslevel: 0,
      };
      newOptions.push(newCategory);
      const { children } = newCategory;
      if (Array.isArray(children)) {
        children.map((child) => {
          const newChildren = {
            ...child,
            csslevel: 2,
          };
          newOptions.push(newChildren);
          if (Array.isArray(newChildren.children)) {
            const subchildl1 = newChildren.children;
            subchildl1.map((subchild2) => {
              const newSubchild2 = {
                ...subchild2,
                csslevel: 5,
              };
              newOptions.push(newSubchild2);
              if (Array.isArray(newSubchild2.children)) {
                const subchild3 = newSubchild2.children;
                subchild3.map((subchildl4) => {
                  const newSubchild4 = {
                    ...subchildl4,
                    csslevel: 7,
                  };
                  newOptions.push(newSubchild4);
                  if (Array.isArray(newSubchild4.children)) {
                    const subchild5 = newSubchild4.children;
                    subchild5.map((subchild6) => {
                      const newSubchild6 = {
                        ...subchild6,
                        csslevel: 9,
                      };
                      newOptions.push(newSubchild6);
                      if (Array.isArray(newSubchild6.children)) {
                        const subchildl7 = newSubchild6.children;
                        subchildl7.map((subchildl8) => {
                          const newSubchild8 = {
                            ...subchildl8,
                            csslevel: 11,
                          };
                          newOptions.push(newSubchild8);
                          if (Array.isArray(newSubchild8.children)) {
                            const subchildl9 = newSubchild8.children;
                            subchildl9.map((subchildl10) => {
                              const newSubchild10 = {
                                ...subchildl10,
                                csslevel: 13,
                              };
                              newOptions.push(newSubchild8);
                            });
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
      setOptions(newOptions);
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
```

basically, i need for a Select component (ReactJS/Material-ui) that renders this Categories and his respective subcategories.

Note that, like a subcategory, is a category with child, and we can have infinite subcategories inside subcategories, something like example below:

```json
[
    {
        ...categoryInfo,
        children: [
            {
                ...subcategoryInfo,
                children: [
                    {
                        ...yesAnewSubcategory,
                        children: [...]

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                ...subcategoryInfo,

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It really build a Select component with the options, i need to show all in a select, but with spaces indicating for this is a subcategory of other category/subcategory.
But, i know, that, in some time, this will reach the limit of Array.isArray(child) inside Array.isArray(child).

EDIT:
this data comes from api request. I want to use a recursion that builds a new Array with each category/subcategory, at the same level in the array, but with the cssLevel incremented for each level of subcategory.

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 34,
      "name": "Serviços Premium",
      "slug": "servicos-premium",
      "cover_image": {
        "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
        "mobile_thumb": {
          "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
        }
      },
      "cover_image_cache": null,
      "icon": {
        "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
        "mobile_thumb": {
          "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
        }
      },
      "icon_cache": null,
      "html_class_name": null,
      "position": 4,
      "aasm_state": "enabled",
      "system_code": 100042,
      "business_id": 3,
      "parent_id": null,
      "parents_count": 0,
      "parents": [null],
      "date_last_sync": null,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "Cats Premium",
          "slug": "cats-premium",
          "cover_image": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "cover_image_cache": null,
          "icon": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "icon_cache": null,
          "html_class_name": null,
          "position": 5,
          "aasm_state": "enabled",
          "system_code": 100043,
          "business_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 34,
          "parents_count": 1,
          "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null],
          "date_last_sync": null,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 36,
              "name": "Cats Premium Male",
              "slug": "cats-premium-male",
              "cover_image": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "cover_image_cache": null,
              "icon": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "icon_cache": null,
              "html_class_name": null,
              "position": 6,
              "aasm_state": "enabled",
              "system_code": 100044,
              "business_id": 3,
              "parent_id": 35,
              "parents_count": 1,
              "parents": [{ "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium" }, null],
              "date_last_sync": null,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": 37,
                  "name": "Cats Premium Female",
                  "slug": "cats-premium-female",
                  "cover_image": {
                    "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                    "mobile_thumb": {
                      "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                    }
                  },
                  "cover_image_cache": null,
                  "icon": {
                    "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                    "mobile_thumb": {
                      "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                    }
                  },
                  "icon_cache": null,
                  "html_class_name": null,
                  "position": 7,
                  "aasm_state": "enabled",
                  "system_code": 100045,
                  "business_id": 3,
                  "parent_id": 36,
                  "parents_count": 1,
                  "parents": [{ "id": 36, "name": "Cats Premium Male" }, null],
                  "date_last_sync": null,
                  "children": [],
                  "chain_name": "Cats Premium Male > Cats Premium Female"
                }
              ],
              "chain_name": "Cats Premium > Cats Premium Male"
            },
            {
              "id": 38,
              "name": "Cats Diamond",
              "slug": "cats-diamond",
              "cover_image": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "cover_image_cache": null,
              "icon": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "icon_cache": null,
              "html_class_name": null,
              "position": 8,
              "aasm_state": "enabled",
              "system_code": 100046,
              "business_id": 3,
              "parent_id": 35,
              "parents_count": 1,
              "parents": [{ "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium" }, null],
              "date_last_sync": null,
              "children": [],
              "chain_name": "Cats Premium > Cats Diamond"
            },
            {
              "id": 45,
              "name": "Subcategoria de Cats Premium",
              "slug": "subcategoria-de-cats-premium",
              "cover_image": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "cover_image_cache": null,
              "icon": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "icon_cache": null,
              "html_class_name": null,
              "position": 15,
              "aasm_state": "enabled",
              "system_code": 100053,
              "business_id": 3,
              "parent_id": 35,
              "parents_count": 1,
              "parents": [{ "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium" }, null],
              "date_last_sync": null,
              "children": [],
              "chain_name": "Cats Premium > Subcategoria de Cats Premium"
            }
          ],
          "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Cats Premium"
        },
        {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "Dogs Diamond",
          "slug": "dogs-diamond",
          "cover_image": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "cover_image_cache": null,
          "icon": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "icon_cache": null,
          "html_class_name": null,
          "position": 9,
          "aasm_state": "enabled",
          "system_code": 100047,
          "business_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 34,
          "parents_count": 1,
          "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null],
          "date_last_sync": null,
          "children": [],
          "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Dogs Diamond"
        },
        {
          "id": 40,
          "name": "Dogs Premium",
          "slug": "dogs-premium",
          "cover_image": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "cover_image_cache": null,
          "icon": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "icon_cache": null,
          "html_class_name": null,
          "position": 10,
          "aasm_state": "enabled",
          "system_code": 100048,
          "business_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 34,
          "parents_count": 1,
          "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null],
          "date_last_sync": null,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 41,
              "name": "Banho Dogs Premium",
              "slug": "banho-dogs-premium",
              "cover_image": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "cover_image_cache": null,
              "icon": {
                "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
                "mobile_thumb": {
                  "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
                }
              },
              "icon_cache": null,
              "html_class_name": null,
              "position": 11,
              "aasm_state": "enabled",
              "system_code": 100049,
              "business_id": 3,
              "parent_id": 40,
              "parents_count": 1,
              "parents": [{ "id": 40, "name": "Dogs Premium" }, null],
              "date_last_sync": null,
              "children": [],
              "chain_name": "Dogs Premium > Banho Dogs Premium"
            }
          ],
          "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Dogs Premium"
        },
        {
          "id": 43,
          "name": "Consulta Veterinária",
          "slug": "consulta-veterinaria",
          "cover_image": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "cover_image_cache": null,
          "icon": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "icon_cache": null,
          "html_class_name": null,
          "position": 13,
          "aasm_state": "enabled",
          "system_code": 100051,
          "business_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 34,
          "parents_count": 1,
          "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null],
          "date_last_sync": null,
          "children": [],
          "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Consulta Veterinária"
        },
        {
          "id": 44,
          "name": "PetCare",
          "slug": "petcare",
          "cover_image": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "cover_image_cache": null,
          "icon": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "icon_cache": null,
          "html_class_name": null,
          "position": 14,
          "aasm_state": "enabled",
          "system_code": 100052,
          "business_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 34,
          "parents_count": 1,
          "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null],
          "date_last_sync": null,
          "children": [],
          "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > PetCare"
        }
      ],
      "chain_name": "Serviços Premium"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Teste 002 edit",
      "slug": "teste-002",
      "cover_image": {
        "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
        "mobile_thumb": {
          "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
        }
      },
      "cover_image_cache": null,
      "icon": {
        "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
        "mobile_thumb": {
          "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
        }
      },
      "icon_cache": null,
      "html_class_name": null,
      "position": 3,
      "aasm_state": "enabled",
      "system_code": 100011,
      "business_id": 3,
      "parent_id": null,
      "parents_count": 0,
      "parents": [null],
      "date_last_sync": null,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 42,
          "name": "Um novo teste",
          "slug": "um-novo-teste",
          "cover_image": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "cover_image_cache": null,
          "icon": {
            "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png",
            "mobile_thumb": {
              "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png"
            }
          },
          "icon_cache": null,
          "html_class_name": null,
          "position": 12,
          "aasm_state": "enabled",
          "system_code": 100050,
          "business_id": 3,
          "parent_id": 3,
          "parents_count": 1,
          "parents": [{ "id": 3, "name": "Teste 002 edit" }, null],
          "date_last_sync": null,
          "children": [],
          "chain_name": "Teste 002 edit > Um novo teste"
        }
      ],
      "chain_name": "Teste 002 edit"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the `csslevel` value? And can you share some example data and the expected output?

Comment: this is the result that the function builds: https://imgur.com/LvNWJ9m, i have updated the ask, with some json data that comes from api.

Comment: Sorry, my internet goes down, when i pressed update button, but now is saved. the csslevel is number of spaces at the select component (as you can see at the image) subcategories, have a space to diff it from the parent category. tha pattern 0, 2, 5, 7 is just the number of spaces, this can be two spaces for each level, without problem

Comment: this will return a single array state (useState([])), with each category/subcategory as an object inside this array. you can see the expected result here: https://api.npoint.io/3e312f1d7ee3b2a601e7 (i recommend json viewer extension cause this json is too bigger).
The objective is use array.map to display each object inside an Select component. using cssLevel to add spaces at leftside of the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each option group, you can call the `getOptions` function which returns the parent category option (with the `name` and `csslevel` properties) and uses [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to map over the children array, recursively calling the `getOptions` function and flattening the result, returning the parent and children options in an array.

```js
const data = [ { "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium", "slug": "servicos-premium", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 4, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100042, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": null, "parents_count": 0, "parents": [null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [ { "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium", "slug": "cats-premium", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 5, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100043, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 34, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [ { "id": 36, "name": "Cats Premium Male", "slug": "cats-premium-male", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 6, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100044, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 35, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [ { "id": 37, "name": "Cats Premium Female", "slug": "cats-premium-female", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 7, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100045, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 36, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 36, "name": "Cats Premium Male" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Cats Premium Male > Cats Premium Female" } ], "chain_name": "Cats Premium > Cats Premium Male" }, { "id": 38, "name": "Cats Diamond", "slug": "cats-diamond", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 8, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100046, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 35, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Cats Premium > Cats Diamond" }, { "id": 45, "name": "Subcategoria de Cats Premium", "slug": "subcategoria-de-cats-premium", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 15, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100053, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 35, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 35, "name": "Cats Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Cats Premium > Subcategoria de Cats Premium" } ], "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Cats Premium" }, { "id": 39, "name": "Dogs Diamond", "slug": "dogs-diamond", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 9, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100047, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 34, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Dogs Diamond" }, { "id": 40, "name": "Dogs Premium", "slug": "dogs-premium", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 10, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100048, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 34, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [ { "id": 41, "name": "Banho Dogs Premium", "slug": "banho-dogs-premium", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 11, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100049, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 40, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 40, "name": "Dogs Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Dogs Premium > Banho Dogs Premium" } ], "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Dogs Premium" }, { "id": 43, "name": "Consulta Veterinária", "slug": "consulta-veterinaria", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 13, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100051, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 34, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > Consulta Veterinária" }, { "id": 44, "name": "PetCare", "slug": "petcare", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 14, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100052, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 34, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 34, "name": "Serviços Premium" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Serviços Premium > PetCare" } ], "chain_name": "Serviços Premium" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Teste 002 edit", "slug": "teste-002", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 3, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100011, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": null, "parents_count": 0, "parents": [null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [ { "id": 42, "name": "Um novo teste", "slug": "um-novo-teste", "cover_image": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "cover_image_cache": null, "icon": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/assets/fallbacks/cover_image-a16120b79ad694c51ee09eabe2cd8ad8.png", "mobile_thumb": { "url": "https://cdn-sandbox.petbooking.com.br/fallbacks/cover_image_mobile_thumb.png" } }, "icon_cache": null, "html_class_name": null, "position": 12, "aasm_state": "enabled", "system_code": 100050, "business_id": 3, "parent_id": 3, "parents_count": 1, "parents": [{ "id": 3, "name": "Teste 002 edit" }, null], "date_last_sync": null, "children": [], "chain_name": "Teste 002 edit > Um novo teste" } ], "chain_name": "Teste 002 edit" } ]

const getOptions = ({ name, children = [], spacing = 0 }) => [
  { name, csslevel: spacing },
  ...children.flatMap((child) =>
    getOptions({ ...child, spacing: spacing + 2 })
  ),
]

const options = data.flatMap(getOptions)
console.log(options)
```

Comment: It really solved my problem! i added a .flat() method into final return of the array, to give just one array and iterates it on my reactjs screen. i dont have words to thank you! i have wasted one week or more, just trying to do this =/. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LucianodiiSouza I wasn't sure of the expected output structure. Just updated my answer to use `flatMap`. Btw, you can add bold styling to the option name if `csslevel` is `0`. You're welcome.